# How to make php api call to CloudFlare to Purge individual files by URL from cache

Tags: api, cloudflare, purge

this code worked good to Purge All files from cache .

Example:

```
$authKey = "MyKEY";
$authEmail = "myEMAIL";

$zoneId = "MYZONEID";
$endpoint = "purge_cache";

$data = [
    "purge_everything" => true
];

$url = "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/{$zoneId}/{$endpoint}";
$opts = ['http' => [
    'method' => 'DELETE',
    'header' => [
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "X-Auth-Key: {$authKey}",
        "X-Auth-Email: {$authEmail}",
    ],
    'content' => json_encode($data),
]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

But I need Purge individual files by URL how can I do that via PHP ?

On api page I found this link:   https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-individual-files-by-url

but I don't now how to make it via php ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass an array with files - like explained on the [API Docs](https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-individual-files-by-url)

In your example that would be something like

```
$data = '{"files":[
  "http://www.example.com/css/styles1.css",
  "http://www.example.com/css/styles2.css",
  "http://www.example.com/css/styles3.css"
]}';
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexT, when I wanted to see what the parameter was called, CF documentation didn't have it, only tags, prefixes and hosts.

Comment: The new CF documentation indeed lacks this information. You can still see it mentioned in the old documentation here: https://web.archive.org/web/20220903154820/https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-files-by-url:~:text=application/json%22%20%5C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%2D%2Ddata%20%27%7B-,%22files%22%3A%5B%22,-https%3A//web.archive